# Execute the contents of a register with a delay after each command

Tags: register

So far, I managed to implement a function that adds a delay after "putting" each character contained in a register to the screen:

```
function! AnimateInsertion() abort
    " split contents of last modified reg in individual chars
    let s:line = split(getreg(v:register), '\zs')
    " iterate through each character
    for s:char in s:line
        sleep 100m
        exe 'normal!a'.s:char
        redraw
    endfor
endfunction
```

[image]

However, this approach treats the contents of the register as a literal string. In other words, this implementation prints an 'i' instead of actually treating it as a command that makes Vim go into insert mode. How could I execute the contents of the register as commands (just like `@<reg>` does) and add a delay after each command is executed?

UPDATE: I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42740081/1706778) 3-year-old question yesterday. It asks pretty much the same as this one. Unfortunately nobody has been able to come up with a solution yet.

Comment: Hard to tell how to modify your code to do what you're asking if you don't show your code...

Comment: Having said that, take a look at [`feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29).

Comment: @filbranden I added the code. I didn't do so initially because I assumed that the solution requires a very different approach. But you are right, for completeness is better to show it.

Comment: @filbranden thanks for the reference to the `feedkeys()` function. It does pretty much what I need. However, I couldn't understand what the term **typeahead** means. Typing `:h typeahead` didn't throw any results either.

Comment: Typeahead is a queue of keystrokes/characters to process. The main problem I had with feedkeys() is that it enqueues all the commands and executes them once the mapping is finished... You can pass feedkeys() a second argument `'x'` or `'x!'` to have it consume the key, but that was a problem when the command was a multi-character command (such as `dd` or `y}`, etc.) Not sure if splitting the string into multiple separate commands would be enough (I'll try that.) Even then, it's hard to do that programatically from a string...

Comment: I tried replacing `execute 'normal! a'.s:char` with `call feedkeys(s:char)`. The first 'i' gets correctly interpreted as an insert command and the rest as characters being typed. The problem I have is that the characters are not entered every 100 ms but all in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fun:

```
com -nargs=+ Type call s:type(<q-args>)

let g:type_interval='200ms'

function s:type(cmd) abort

  " spawn a timer_start for every char, the inner lambda call feedkeys with
  " captured current char.
  call map(split(a:cmd, '\zs'),
        \ { i,v -> timer_start( g:type_interval * i, { t -> feedkeys(v) } ) })
endfunction

exe "Type Gohello\<esc>oworld\<esc>ciwvim\<esc>dddd"
```

source it, it will jump to end of file, typing `hello world`, then change `world` to `vim`, then delete lines one by one. If you type in the middle, you will mess it, I hope that's not a problem.

This works like every character is typed one by one, it doesn't care about
`mapping delay` and `keycode delay`, something like this will never wrok:

```
" turn on timeout, make sure timeoutlen is greater than type interval
set timeout
let &timeoutlen=1000
let g:type_interval='100ms'

nnoremap abc dd
Type abc
```

The `a` never get it's `bc`, can't tell why.  It also breaks if you use multi
bytes keycodes (such as `"\<c-right>"`).

**Update to address comment**

If you want to place the command in a register and hide the execution part:

```
let @x = "Type Gohello\<esc>oworld\<esc>ciwvim\<esc>dddd"
nnoremap <silent> <leader>x :exe @x<cr>
```

**To support abort**

We can't use command to abort, the animation will mess our typing, we can only use single key map to do it, we need to create map in all mods:

```
noremap <f4> <c-\><c-n>:call timer_stopall()<cr>
noremap! <f4> <c-\><c-n>:call timer_stopall()<cr>
tnoremap <f4> <c-\><c-n>:call timer_stopall()<cr>
```

I use `timer_stopall()` for simplicity here. If you want to be precise, you can record it in the `s:type` and loop them one by one to stop it.

Comment: Oh wow this is great. It works just as you describe. My goal is to use this to automate live coding sessions (to avoid typos and speed up the typing). The only thing I'm missing is to be able to this transparently, for example, store `Gohello\<esc>oworld\<esc>ciwvim\<esc>dddd` in a register and use @ to run it. I tried doing this with your example but the invisible characters don't get correctly interpreted.

Comment: @mroavi Could you be specific ? There has no invisible character except `esc` in the example, I changed it to call from register in the update, it works fine.

Comment: In your example, to start the animation, I have to type `exe @q` in the command line. I would like to start the animation just by typing `@q` (just like a normal macro).

Comment: The idea behind this is that I only want students to see the animation and not me starting the animation. Maybe this could be done more easily with a mapping?

Comment: @mroavi You can store the `:exe ...` part in another register, see update for example. `map` of course works too.

Comment: @mroavi If you want to hide everything, you should use `:h map-silent`.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much.